# When trying to run Aries2 repo, getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/availity/aries/core/queue/QueueStorage error

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

When attempting to run the pdm-outbound (Aries2 app) repo, we are getting the following error.  This is a new error and was not occurring last week.  I have conformed that devtools is up to date and rebuilt gradle.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/availity/aries/core/queue/QueueStorage
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3103)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at com.availity.aries.core.plugin.Plugins.init(Plugins.java:207)
    at com.availity.aries.Aries.start(Aries.java:259)
    at com.availity.aries.Aries.bootstrap(Aries.java:146)
    at com.availity.aries.Aries.main(Aries.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.availity.aries.core.queue.QueueStorage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this issue on my local. It appears like there is some issue with

> com.availity.aries.core:vault:**3.3.0**-SNAPSHOT

So, the immediate fix would be to revert to the previous version i.e

> com.availity.aries.core:vault:**3.2.0**-SNAPSHOT

Navigate to the *devtools* folder on your local machine and locate the file *launcher.gradle* [line 57](https://git.availity.com/projects/CORE/repos/devtools/browse/launcher.gradle#57) . Revert it to the previous version as indicated above. Once this is done, execute the command

```
./gradle.sh clean compileJava launcher
```

The app should run without the error. The concerned team would look into this and get a fix ASAP.